# Power cuts out when I wiggle positive battery terminal

Tags: battery

Power cuts out when I wiggle positive battery terminal right when I wiggle it left power comes back on megane 225 please help when I put foot on accelerator it feels like I'm being g pushed backwards hard and internal light comes on :(

Comment: What is your question? If it is about the terminal, then you obviously have a loose connection. If it is about the acceleration then you need to update your post to explain what the problem is

Comment: Many people will be jealous of you car's acceleration :)  can you explain more?

Comment: Yes indeed @HandyHowie , yes indeed.

Comment: @robkershaw  did you tighten the battery terminal or just notice it and move on??

Answer (score 2):

Your alternator has to be checked because of the terminal wiggle. More so the vehicle is having some electrical body ground contact which causes the light to come on when not operated.

Comment: We want you to be here so we've helped you a little. I've edited your post to make it clearer to read. Please remember, we have an international community here where English may not be their first language. Please consider these people when you write something so that it makes sense. Using non-words, concatenation, and no punctuation doesn't help things.

Comment: Whaoo!! I am new here but no problem I will dance to the tune of the community. Thanks a lot.